# Start module activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, module, android-library

I created an Android Studio project, next clicked on File/New/Import module and selected the project directory of an opensource project.

Next, in the build.gradle (app), I added:

```
  dependencies {
      compile project(':moduleName')
  }
```

It seems to works, because I have two configurations: one for my project and one for the module. 
I can run my project or the module, but I would like to start a module activity from my main project when I press on a button.
How can I do?

In particular I want to create an application that incorporates this opensource project: https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn

And I would like to start the main activity of that project from one button in the Activity of my application.
I want to do this so to not install two applications (the opensource project one and mine), but only one (mine).

Wish you can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

In androidManifest file put intent filter tag to the activity to which you want to start when app is launched.

Comment: Hi, I mean, how to start a module activity from the main project?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Home">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Subactivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

This is an Android manifest file of my project , `<activity android:name=".Home">` ,this is the main activity which opens at the start of the app and the second one is `<activity android:name=".Subactivity">  </activity>` . If you want the second activity as your main activity , just cut same Intent filter which is present in the  `<activity android:name=".Home">` copy to the `<activity android:name=".Subactivity">`

Comment: Hi, I mean, how to start a module activity from the main project?

Comment: Can you post the important code , so i can understand it @helloimyourmind

Comment: I edit my first post again, wish you can understand me now.